# QMediaPlayer wrong parse url with cyrillic on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cyrillic, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to play translation:

```
QString language = "ru";
QString text = "Привет мир";
QUrl preparedUrl = QUrl("http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=gtx&tl=" + language + "&q=" + text);
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(preparedUrl);
player->play();
```

On Windows this text playing "Знак опроса" for each symbol (this means "question mark" on English). This problems exists only with cyrillic.
On Linux this code works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the encoding?

Comment: Change `QString text = "Привет мир";` to `QString text = QString::fromUTF8( "Привет мир");

Comment: @Evgeny, it did't help:( As SteakOverflow mentioned, it it is not need for Qt5 which I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Evgeny mentioned, `QString::fromUTF8` might help you, but only if you are using Qt4. In Qt5, `QString(const char *)` and `QString::operator=(const char *)` both already use `QString::fromUTF8` (according to the documentation).

I think your problem is the file encoding. Make sure your c++ source file is stored in UTF-8 encoding.

There is also `QString::fromLocal8Bit` which might help you if you cannot store the file in UTF-8.

---

**Update:**
Tried that on Windows 7, does not work. Consider the below proof of concept for a working version. The `#if 0` block should be identical to the `#else` one, but doen't work either. I would consider this a bug in the DirectShow backend. You might to try to get the WMF backed running, but I have never tried that.

```
    QUrl preparedUrl = QUrl("http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=gtx&tl=ru&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82 %D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80");
    QNetworkRequest request(preparedUrl);
#if 0
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setMedia(request);
    player->play();
#else
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QNetworkReply * reply = mgr.get(request);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply, preparedUrl]()
    {
        QByteArray * ba = new QByteArray(reply->readAll());
        QBuffer * buffer = new QBuffer(ba);
        buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        delete reply;

        QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
        player->setMedia(preparedUrl, buffer);
        player->play();
    });
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps, I changed `QString text = "Привет мир"` to `QString text = QString::fromLocal8Bit("Привет мир")`.
In my program I'm trying to get text from PlainTextEdit by toPlainText() function and send received text in another function that must to speech it, but have the same encoding problem. Why could this happening?

Comment: Within the same program, this should not be happening. If you are trying to export it to a file again or something, use the reverse function `toLocal8Bit()`. Or make sure the other program can handle unicode input.

Comment: But I don't read data from any file. It so strange...
Could you check example of my code?
https://pastebin.com/2tF9nVL3

Comment: Works for me. Just like the the original example.

Comment: Thanks for testing! Hm... So strange. Did you use Windows and cyrilic symbols?

Comment: Tested on linux with Qt5 and the Cyrillic string from the original question

Comment: On Linux this works for me too. This bug exists only on Windows :(

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works! But I changed the lambda function to QEventLoop.